# page breaks at specific lines in asp.net

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net

Is it possible to put line breaks on asp.net web page when the web page exceeds certain number of lines so if my web page has 15 lines then I want a page break after the 15th line and if my web page has 11 lines then I don't want a page break.

any help will be appreciated

Comment: You mean like a page break for if someone were printing your web page? You need to explain what you want better, as you can't assume we know exactly what you're talking about.

Comment: you could use js to check the height of the document and if it exceeds a certain height, then add an element to the page that would cause the [page-break](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/page-break/)

Answer (score 0):

You would probably be much better off using a PDF generator than HTML for this.

There's a CSS attibute - `page-break-after` but I really don't use it. You'd just apply this to a class or tag and use it where needed.

You're hard-coding a page break - these are bad enough in Word where it's pretty much consistent across machines, in HTML you're going to be in for some fun times since you're dealing with browsers, and sometimes a point size in one is different in another...